# Exceeding GitHub file size limit when trying to use Git Large File Storage

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

I'm trying to push a csv file larger than 100Mb to my remote repository using git lfs. I have downloaded and install the git lfs, ran the command lines `git lfs track "*.csv"` and `git add .gitattributes`. Then I did the regular commit and push. However I'm still getting an error message saying the file exceeded the Github file size limit:

```
remote: error: File store-sales-time-series-forecasting/train.csv is 116.16 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
```

Here are my commit and push commands if it helps with anything:

```
git commit -m "try to add large files"
[main af9a7a5] try to add large files
 7 files changed, 20 insertions(+), 142140 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 .gitattributes
```

```
git push origin main
Uploading LFS objects: 100% (7/7), 125 MB | 1.1 MB/s, done.
Enumerating objects: 24, done.
Counting objects: 100% (24/24), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (24/24), done.
Writing objects: 100% (24/24), 21.08 MiB | 2.18 MiB/s, done.
Total 24 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1), done.
remote: error: Trace: 5491bae84ff4b6ed56c0c0d2a7deb7385afd477d66fa0dfd9ba495e47b73a262
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File store-sales-time-series-forecasting/train.csv is 116.16 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
To https://github.com/dji627/Test-large-file.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/dji627/Test-large-file.git'
```

Comment: Maybe you should have used `"*.csv"` instead of `".csv"` in the `git lfs track` command.

Comment: I tried "*.csv" but still getting the same error

Comment: Sounds like the file might have existed in the repository before you added git lfs?

Comment: @fredrik, yes, does that make a difference?

Comment: @Dan yes github check all the files in the commits you push to prevent big files to be pushed. You have to rewrite your history to remove the big csv file from the first commit where you introduced it. `git lfs migrate` could maybe help you. Have a look...

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that large file was previously committed in your history.

Use [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo)  (python module, to be [installed first](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/INSTALL.md)), with some [content-based filtering](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#_content_based_filtering):

```
git filter-repo --strip-blobs-bigger-than 10M
```

That would remove any blob bigger than 10Mb, for instance.
You will need to force push (`git push --force`: easy if you are the only one working on the repository) the result, and see if the issue persists.